# Is it possible to indicate a type that it contains certain properties at runtime?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get a type that contains properties defined in a string array, at runtime. Is this ever possible with Typescript type system?

```
const props = ["a", "b", "c"];

function f(props): <????> {
// ...
}

const instance = f(props);
instance.a; // ok
instance.z; // compiler error
```

How should the resulting type be defined, then?

Comment: What do you mean by "defined in a string array at runtime"? The code you've posted defines keys at compile time. Are you saying `props` in your code would actually be unknown?

Comment: Props will be an array of strings unknown at compile time

Comment: Then it's really not possible. Compiler can only type check things known at compile time. For run-time type checking there are various libraries out there, such as [ts-runtime](https://github.com/fabiandev/ts-runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to go from a union of keys to an object type (the predefined mapped type `Record` will do the trick). You also need to help type inference infer a tuple type of string literals for the `props` constant instead of string as we need the  information about exactly what strings are in the array to be preserved

```
function tuple<T extends string[]>(...a: T) :T{
  return a;
}

const props = tuple("a", "b", "c");

function f<T extends Array<keyof any>>(props:T): Record<T[number], string> {
  return null!;
}

const instance = f(props);
instance.a; // ok
instance.z; // compiler error
```

Comment: Awesome! is it ever possible to do it without rest arg (...a) and with an string array instead somehow?

Comment: Yeah, this still only works if you know the prop keys at compile-time.

Comment: @Aaron yes, that was my reading of the question.. If you don't know the keys then there is no static type checking to speak of with regard to the keys

Comment: @DanielSan you can type the `const` manually (`const props: ['a', 'b', 'c'] = ['a','b', 'c']`)but you are probably better off with the function